# Open source tool for Rest API Adapter

Tags: rest, integration

Is there any good open source framework for Rest API Adapter, API adapter use cases :

- Maps the REST API source request body signature to target request body signature and source response body signature to target response body signature and which has to be configurable.

For Example :

Source API expects Json :

```
{
"name" : "testing name 1" 
}
```

Target API expects Json

```
  {
 "name_t1" : "testing name 1" 
}
```

the name and name_t1 has to be mapped to two rest APIs to function and similarly for mapping of response bodies from source to target. This is a simple example the source and target request API has nested multi-dimensional arrays.
Is there any good framework which does this job?

Regards

Kris

Comment: You could at least have a look at [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen it seems that its not having an UI for mapping properties, moreover its using okhttp